# building a simple search form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to build a simple search form in Ruby on Rails, my form is simple enough basically you select fields from a series of options and then all the events matching the fields are shown. The problem comes when I leave any field blank.

Here is the code responsible for filtering the parameters

```
Event.joins(:eventdates).joins(:categories).where
("eventdates.start_date = ? AND city = ? AND categories.name = ?", 
params[:event][:date], params[:event][:city], params[:event][:category]).all
```

From what I get it's that it looks for events with any empty field, but since all of them have them not empty, it wont match unless all 3 are filled, another problem arises when I try to say, look events inside a range or array of dates, I'm clueless on how to pass multiple days into the search.

I'm pretty new to making search forms in general, so I don't even know if this is the best approach, also I'm trying to keep the searches without the need of a secialized model.

Answer (score 5):

Below is probably what you are looking for. (Note: If all fields all blank, it shows all data in the events table linkable with eventdates and categories.)

```
events = Event.joins(:eventdates).joins(:categories)
if params[:event]
  # includes below where condition to query only if params[:event][:date] has a value
  events = events.where("eventdates.start_date = ?", params[:event][:date]) if params[:event][:date].present?
  # includes below where condition to query only if params[:event][:city] has a value
  events = events.where("city = ?", params[:event][:city]) if params[:event][:city].present?
  # includes below where condition to query only if params[:event][:city] has a value
  events = events.where("categories.name = ?", params[:event][:category]) if params[:event][:category].present?
end
```

To search using multiple days:

```
# params[:event][:dates] is expected to be array of dates. 
# Below query gets converted into an 'IN' operation in SQL, something like "where eventdates.start_date IN ['date1', 'date2']"
events = events.where("eventdates.start_date = ?", params[:event][:dates]) if params[:event][:dates].present?
```

Comment: This one is really good, however I'll hold on for a while until I get the below answer fully implemented, still this one is far easier to understand.

Comment: `@events.all.distinct.each` makes it so that all events get listed once if they have multiple categories.

Answer (score 4):

**It will be more easy and optimised . If you use concern for filter data.**

Make one concern in Model.

filterable.rb

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
     results = self.where(nil)
     filtering_params.each do |key, value|
       if column_type(key) == :date || column_type(key) == 
       :datetime
         results = results.where("DATE(#{column(key)}) = ?", 
         Date.strptime(value, "%m/%d/%Y")) if 
         value.present?  
       else
         results = results.where("#{column(key)} Like ? ", "%#{value}%") if 
         value.present?
       end
     end
     results
    end

   def resource_name
    self.table_name
   end

   def column(key)
    return key if key.split(".").count > 1
    return "#{resource_name}.#{key}"
   end

   def column_type(key)
    self.columns_hash[key].type
   end
  end
end
```

Include this concern in model file that you want to filter.

Model.rb

```
 include Filterable
```

In your controller Add this methods

```
def search
    @resources = Model.filter(class_search_params)
    render 'index'
end


def class_search_params
    params.slice(:id,:name) #Your field names
end
```

**So, It is global solution. You dont need to use query for filter. just add this concern in your model file. 
    That's it.**

Comment: I'm having problems implementing this solution, no matter the input I send through the search method it returns all posible events, even when left blank, even if my form is as simple as `f.text_field :name`, so I dunno what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Bluespheal Did you made route of search ? if yes than just put exit in `filter` method . you can trash there. what is your key and value. key and value is most important. ! let me know if you still face issue .

Comment: yeah, I have the search route and the index view, problem is that all possible events get listed I don't see neither key nor value, the only parameters I see that go trough are `city:`, `date:` and `category:` all inside `event` maybe I'm missing something, what confuses me the most is how key and value are handled.

Comment: @Bluespheal Key is your field name which you want to filter by and value is value of that field which you entered for search. e.g. you enter "test" in your text field name and search it.. than name become key and value become test. got it ?

Comment: Oh! now I get it, still I'm unable to filter the values  `date: '2017-06-30'`, `city: Tulum`, `category: Cultura` gets passed on, but all events get listed using `@resources.each do |event|` I feel I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Okay Let me customize the method for date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148083/discussion-between-bluespheal-and-vishal).