# Ruby on Rails: Search for database items (students)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 questions.

I want to add a search to my database. All items of my database are shown at the main page, there's a list where you can see all of the students. Can anyone tell me how I can add a function to my search? Where should I start, what should I create? And can you also tell me what any of that steps are doing? And how can I display the search results?

```html
  <p class="lead">Student management at a glance.
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <!-- Search should be here -->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Student Summary -->
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> Students
          <div class="btn-group float-right">
            <%= link_to new_student_path, :class => "btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" do %>
            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>
            New
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
          <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead class="thead">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><i class="fas fa-hashtag"></div></i></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><%= sort_link "surname", "Name, Surname" %></div></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><%= sort_link "room_id", "Room" %></div></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><%= sort_link "harddrive_id", "Hard Drive" %></div></th>
<th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><%= sort_link "key_id", "Key" %></div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><%= sort_link "os", "OS" %></div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><%= sort_link "manager" %></div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><%= sort_link "pawn" %></div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><%= sort_link "eol", "EOL" %></div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><%= sort_link "comment" %></div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="btn btn-fhg-0"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div></i></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% counter = 1 %>
          <% @students.each do |student| %>
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle"><%= counter %></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><%= student.to_s %></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><%= Room.find(student.room_id).to_s %></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><%= student.harddrive %></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><%= student.key %></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><%= student.os.capitalize %></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><%= student.manager %></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><%= student.pawn ? 'Paid' : 'Not paid' %></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><%= student.eol.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></td>
            <td class="align-middle" data-toggle="popover" title="<%= student.to_s %>" data-content="<%= student.comment %>"><%= truncate(student.comment, length: 30, separator: ' ') %></td>
            <td>
```

I also want to list the amount of items of a category I have saved in my database. As example:

There are 50 students, 60 hard drives, 70 keys and 80 rooms.
Is it possible to list the exact amount of items on my page? Something like

```
<h1>There are <%= amount of students %> total queries.</h1>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do have so far? What are your models? With which attributes?

Comment: You need to search with attribute by filter ? O search a simple string inside DB ?

Comment: If you are using `ActiveRecord`, which I'm assuming you do, checkout [this overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#read) and this [detailed explaination](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for further information about querying.

Comment: Here's a little recipe of my index.html.erb (show above). How the search should work: Type something into it (surname, room_id (you should get all results related to the room_id and so on)) and get a new view of the search results.

Comment: @absolado Please take look at my this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816633/5117953

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `StudentsController` and add a search method in it to search for the students.

eg. below `search` method will search students on the basis of name

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def search  
    @students = Student.where(name: params[:name])  
  end
end
```

And in routes

```
resources :students do  
  collection do
    get :search  
  end  
end
```