# ActiveRecord how to use Where only if the parameter you're querying has been passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm running a query like the below:

```
Item.where("created_at >=?", Time.parse(params[:created_at])).where(status_id: params[:status_id])
```

...where the user can decide to NOT provide a parameter, in which case it should be excluded from the query entirely. For example, if the user decides to not pass a `created_at` and not submit it, I want to run the following:

```
Item.where(status_id: params[:status_id])
```

I was thinking even if you had a `try` statement like `Time.try(:parse, params[:created_at])`, if `params[created_at]` were empty, then the query would be `.where(created_at >= ?", nil)` which would NOT be the intent at all. Same thing with `params[:status_id]`, if the user just didn't pass it, you'd have a query that's `.where(status_id:nil)` which is again not appropriate, because that's a valid query in itself!

I suppose you can write code like this:

```
if params[:created_at].present?
  @items = Item.where("created_at >= ?", Time.parse(params[:created_at])
end
if params[:status_id].present?
  @items = @items.where(status_id: params[:status_id])
end
```

However, this is less efficient with multiple db calls, and I'm trying to be more efficient. Just wondering if possible.

Comment: If you are building filter or search functionality, please go with my this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816633/5117953

Comment: @SimpleLime is right: `q = M.where(a, b)`, `q = M.where(a).where(b)`, and `q = M.where(a); q = q.where(b)` are equivalent for queries like yours. And `q` won't hit the database until you try to read rows from it.

Comment: sorry I know this doesn't relate but still asking what if user provide nothing? are you willing to give any data?

Comment: @Manishh oh there's validation before this that says the user must provide one of the two. but i suppose to further the example, I would like a world where if no params were provided, no data comes back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index
  @products = Product.where(nil) # creates an anonymous scope
  @products = @products.status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
  @products = @products.location(params[:location]) if params[:location].present?
  @products = @products.starts_with(params[:starts_with]) if params[:starts_with].present?
end
```

You can do something like this. Rails is smart in order to identify when it need to build query ;)

You might be interested in checking [this blog](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/) It was very useful for me and can also be for you.

Comment: how would you change this to meet the hypothetical situation where if no params are passed nothing is returned? or is that possible?

Comment: @james in that case you'd use `@products = Product.none`. And instead of `Product.where(nil)` you can also use `Product.all` to get a blank scope.

Comment: @james I think this is business call you should confirm once what need to be done in that case. Whatever is the requirement you need to do accordingly.

Comment: @Stefan it looks like if you use `Product.all`, same thing as `Product.where(nil)`, where `@products` will always contain all the products, so if no params were passed, I'm still stuck with all products. On the other hand using `Product.none` does provide 0 products, but now even if params are passed, I can't build anything else going forward, because a query on nothing returns nothing. Guess there's no way to do this?

Comment: @james use an `if-else` construct. Check whether `params` contains `:created_at` or `:status_id`. If it does, use `@items = Item.all` and refine the query via `@items = @items.where(...)`. Otherwise, use `@items = Item.none`

Comment: i'll just keep my validation, thnks!

Answer (score 0):

If you read [#where](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) documentation, you can see option to pass `nil` to where clause.

> blank condition : 
>   If the condition is any blank-ish object, then #where is a no-op and returns the current relation.

This gives us option to pass conditions if valid or just return nil will produce previous relation itself.

```
@items = Item.where(status_condition).where(created_at_condition)

private

def status_condition
  ['status = ?', params[:status]] unless params[:status].blank?
end

def created_at_condition
  ['created_at >= ?', Time.parse(params[:created_at])] unless params[:created_at].blank?
end
```

This would be another option to achieve the desired result. Hope this helps !

Comment: String interpolation without any attempt at quoting? What's wrong with `{ status: params[:status] } unless...` and `['created_at >= ?', Time.parse(...)]` unless...`?